# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}(x^2 + b^2)} $

Tags: calculus, integration

I am wondering if it is possible to evaluate the following integral in closed form:
$$
I(a,b) = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}(x^2 + b^2)}
$$
For the special case $a = b$, Mathematica gives
$$
I(a,a) = \frac{K_1 (|a|)}{|a|}
$$
I am wondering if there is also a formula when the parameters are different.

Comment: Mathematica tells us that
$$I(a,a)=\frac{K_1(| a| )}{| a| }$$

Comment: Suppose $|a|>|b|$ and let $c = a/b > 1$. Then contour integration can transform the integral to $[\pi/(2b^2)]e^{-b}/\sqrt{c^2-1}-b^{-2}\int_1^\infty \exp(-b c u)/[\sqrt{u^2-1}(c^2u^2-1)]$. Admittedly I'm not sure that's any easier...

Comment: I can also get it as a convolution integral: $b I(a,b) = \exp(-b)\cos^{-1}(b/a)/\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-\int_0^1 K_0(a u)\sinh[b(1-u)] du$. Maybe there's a Laplace transform-based approach to this one.

Comment: Correction: there should be $\cosh(b)$, not $\exp(-b)$, in that expression.